# Will trying to flash an unofficial update with stock recovery harm my device?

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, customization

I have an Android tablet, the DigiLand DL718M, with a stock recovery that can do slightly more than expected. It isn't much, but I have high hopes that it will support flashing SuperSu using the recovery. My question is, if I try to flash it to test it out and it turns out that my stock recovery cannot install custom updates, will it damage my firmware or something like that, or just pop up an error message telling me I'm an idiot?

PS: I'm explicitly asking about the stock recovery for a good reason: This device's bootloader is not unlockable, so I cannot install a custom recovery.

Comment: Dont do unofficial flashing via stock recoveries. Use custom recoveries like TWRP or CWM.

Comment: Yeah, I certainly wish I could! So far I've only been able to use the stock recovery, and I was feeling optimistic yesterday.

Comment: Nonny, you might ask a separate question on how to install some custom recovery (or use it without installation: TWRP e.g. allows to "just be booted" without being installed) – of course after verifying such a question doesn't already exist. The culprit most likely will be availability: there rarely are custom recoveries for tablets. Checking on XDA cannot hurt, that's the most likely place to find such.

Comment: @Izzy thanks, but I was actually asking about the stock recovery. This device's bootloader is not unlockable.

Comment: Ah! That fact should go directly into your question to avoid recommendations like "better use a custom recovery" – it would make pretty clear why you're asking that way around! Done that for you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stock recovery should just fail, it will look for a digitally signed package from the manufacturer, not find it, and error out without making changes. If the developer who made the package specifically made it to work for that device and spoofed the signature somehow, it could do anything from work perfectly to perma-brick the device, hard to say.

Comment: Thanks! The update does nothing of the sort, so it will accurately determine what I want to know.

Comment: Yeah. It didn't even bother to tell me the error, instead saying "installation aborted".